# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have that error after running that code.

```
import gym
import random
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from statistics import mean, median
from collections import Counter

LR = 1e-3
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
goal_steps = 500
score_requirement = 50
initial_games = 10000


def some_random_games_first():
   for episode in range(5):
       env.reset()
       for t in range(goal_steps):
            env.render()
            action = env.action_space.sample()
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

            if done:
                break


some_random_games_first()
```

Here is the error. What should i do to make it work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ziyaarslan/PycharmProjects/mlearning/test1.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Its give me a link but it doesn't work.
also where i can learn machine learning?

Thanks for everyone who tried to help)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib

I think this is your problem maybe. You have not got this library yet.
IF you want to learn ML only, maybe switching back to tensorflow CPU is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

try to upgrade your tf

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```